# Badly drawn mouse cursor with grey circle flickering between default mouse cursor on Lenovo Thinkpad X220 Tablet with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse, thinkpad

There is a Lenovo Thinkpad X220 Tablet with all manner of strange Lenovo crapware installed on it.  It also has touch screen Windows 7 installed, also not something I'm familiar with.  I'm not blaming the crapware but it is entirely possible this is the source of the mysterious flickering cursor below:

[image: flicking between the default arrow and one with a gray circle below a badly drawn arrow]

The user restarted the machine and still had the same issue.   The flickering cursor also interferes a great deal with the user ability to click.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: A user at work? Is this a company supplied tablet?

Comment: Yes it is. Why?

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: Fine now it's not about work.  And I am in the IT department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's [Chiral Scrolling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUFxeZz7qvw) (see the video in the link).  It can be turned off in the UltraNav control panel.  (someone on the Lenvo Forums told me)